# How do I update a branch to be the state of a tag on a different branch in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, tags, branch

I have a repository with a `master` and a `develop` branch.

I want to create a third named branch, say it's called `bugfixes`.

I want to be able to update to `bugfixes` and then have the tip of `bugfixes` be the same as a previous tag on `master`. (Say that tag is called `Release5.1`).

I've tried updating to the branch, and then updating to the tag, but that switches the branch back to `master` (where the tag is). I've also tried merging

`hg merge -r Release5.1`

but that only brought in the changes and didn't cause the branch to "go back in time".

How do I get that tag to the the tip of the named branch?

I'm asking this question because my CruiseControl.net guy tells me that we can only do builds off of the tips of branches and not off of specific revisions.  (Maybe that is another question....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First some basics:**

Merges are directional:

- When you merge `bugfixes` into `master`, then `master` gets the changesets that were committed on the `bugfixes` branch.
- When you merge `master` into `bugfixes`, then the reverse happens.

If you want two branches to mirror each other, then you must do the merge in both directions.

---

**I would argue that you don't need the `bugfixes` branch at all.**  Instead, I would set a policy that says:

- `master` should always be in a state that may be released
- Bug fixes are committed to `master`
- All releases are tags on `master`
- New features are committed to `develop`
- When it is time to release, `develop` is merged into `master`
- After every release, `master` is merged into `develop` to insure that new features are based on the latest release.

This would result in something like this:

[image: workflow with no bugfixes branch]

---

**If you must have a `bugfixes` branch, then I set a policy like this:**

- `master` should always be in a state that may be released
- All releases are tags on `master`
- Bug fixes are committed to `bugfixes`
- New features are committed to `develop`
- When it is time to for a bug fix release:

  1. Merge `bugfixes` into `master`
  2. Tag `master`
  3. Merge `master` into `bugfixes` to make them match
  4. Merge `master` into `develop` to make sure new features are based on the latest release.
- When it is time for a major release:

  1. Merge `bugfixes` into `master`
  2. Merge `develop` into `master`
  3. Tag `master`
  4. Merge `master` into `bugfixes` to make them match
  5. Merge `master` into `develop` to make sure new features are based on the latest

This will result in something that looks like this:

[image: workflow with bugfix branch]

---

**To fix a bug in an old revision, you should:**

```
hg update <TAG>
hg branch Release1.x
<fix the bug>
hg commit -m "Bug fix to older version"
hg tag Release1.2

...if the bug is present in master, then you should also:
hg update master
hg merge Release1.x
hg commit -m "merged bug fix in Release1.x to master"
```

This would result in something like this:

[image: bug fix to older release]

**NOTE 1:** At this point, `master` has commits which should never be part of a `Release1.x` release.  Due to this, you should never merge `master` into `Release1.x`.

**NOTE 2:** If you must support multiple releases of a product in the field, it is common to have a named branch for each major release.  These long-running named branches are then used only for bug fixes.  If you are very careful, you can merge bug fixes from one release branch to another, but in my experience it is more common to use `hg transplant` to copy the changes between branches.

Comment: Tim -- thanks for taking the time to answer, but I don't think that you've quite covered my issue.  May I impose further?  My problem is that I need to to a bug fix off of a point in time "in the past" of master.  For instance, we have released 5.0 and 5.1.  Now I need to release a bug fix for 5.0.  How do I get a named branch based on teh 5.0 codebase?

Comment: @Nick: I added a section to my answer for fixing bugs in an old release.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you keep the `bugfixes` branch essentially a mirror of the `master` branch except for when you are fixing a bug, and once the bug is fixed, merge `bugfix` back into `master` to again sync them up.

If you need to maintain multiple old versions of `master`, you will probably need to have a `bugfix` named branch for each old version you need to maintain.

Ideally, you wouldn't need a named branch dedicated to bug fixes. Much of Mercurial's power comes from how easy it is to branch from a previous revision (un-named branch). I am not too familiar with CruiseControl.net, but if you can build off of unnamed branches, then all you would have to do is:

1. Update to the tag you want to base the fix on
2. Make the changes
3. Commit (this will make an unnamed branch)
4. Build / test the tip of the new, unnamed branch
5. Tag the new version
6. Merge as needed to make sure all code lines get the bug fix

Due to how Mercurial's internal hash structure works, unwinding changes off of the "stack" (or inserting new changesets into the stack, depending on how you look at it) is a really, really hard thing to do and is likely to break any repositories that were clones of the one you are working on.